# Subir aplicación PHP a servidor

Tags: php

Tengo una página en un hosting de GoDaddy, estoy tratando de subir mi aplicación pero al momento en que ingreso toda la carpeta me marca error, me dice que no se ha encontrado el servidor, en una página de `config.php` tengo definida la ruta de la siguiente manera

```
define('RUTA', 'http://www.subdominio.ruta.com/');
```

y en otros archivos la mando a llamar solo para saber si se ha iniciado sesion y en caso de que no me direccione a login

```
function comprobarSession() {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        header('Location: ' . RUTA . 'login.php');
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la aplicación en localhost obvio si funciona si le pongo el nombre de la carpeta en la que lo tengo por ejemplo

```
define('RUTA', 'http://localhost/carpetaDeArchivo/');
```

Comment: que llamas con carpeta de archivo???, es decir tienes todo el proyecto en una carpeta de tu localhost, o archivos específicos de tu sitio. Por otro lado, cuanto tiempo tienes con este hosting??, recuerda que las ***dns*** de un dominio tardan mínimo 24 horas en propagarse, por otro lado parece ser un problema con el servidor o configuración de tu hosting y no de php a simple vista.

Comment: mandaste llamar al archivo que tiene la constante?

Comment: ¿Si ingresas en la dirección subdominio.ruta.com directamente en el navegador, puedes entrar? ¿Si haces un ping en el servidor a esa dirección, responde?

Comment: Que tal a todos! con el hosting lo compre hoy e hice los subdominios inmediatamente despues de que se configuro el CPanel, posteriormente ingrese un archivo index.php para asegurarme de que si estuviera funcionando y si funcionaba. el error que creo que hacia era ponerle en la ruta http://www.subdominio.dominio.com

Comment: ¿Entonces el problema ya está resuelto?

Comment: si @AlvaroMontoro ya se resolvio quitando el www.

Comment: pregunta de noob que dice la documentacion que debe ser RUTA???

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estas intentando subir una aplicación en PHP al servidor en GoDaddy, tienes que tener varias cosas en consideración:

Cuando creas un subdominio generalmente lo que hacen es crear una re-dirección a esos nombres desde una carpeta, generalmente esto es configurable desde el CPanel.

Lo que no entiendo es esa definición de una URL usando PHP, no se para que la necesitas.

Lo que yo haría es ir a la parte de subdomion del CPanel y mirar en que directorio esta apuntando y subir los archivos de tu proyecto ahí.

Saludos,